# POST with Restlet framework for Java

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I can make a GET with no problem at all.
When trying it with a POST request, I get this message:

> Internal Server Error 
>   The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

I'm testing it with Simple REST Client extension for Chrome, but I get the same message in the real application.

This is my post:

```
   @Post
   public StringRepresentation pepe(Representation entity) {
      StringRepresentation result = this.users();  

      // Parse the given representation and retrieve data
      Form form = new Form(entity);  
      String action = form.getFirstValue("action");  

      if(action.equals("add")){
        //nothing
      }

      Db.closeConnection();

      return result;
   }
```

And this is my @Get working properly:

```
 @Get
   public StringRepresentation pepe() {
      String action = getQuery().getValues("action");
      StringRepresentation result = null;

      result = this.users();

      Db.closeConnection();

      return result;
   }
```

And the funny thing is: whenever I remove the condition `if(action.equals("add")){`, **(which was empty inside)** the POST works correctly.
This would work:

```
   @Post
   public StringRepresentation pepe(Representation entity) {
      StringRepresentation result = this.users();  

      // Parse the given representation and retrieve data
      Form form = new Form(entity);  
      String action = form.getFirstValue("action");  

      Db.closeConnection();

      return result;
   }
```

What's going on? Looks so random!

Comment: check if your "action" variable is not null. You might have a NullPointerException that you are not seeing.

Comment: Yep, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your variable `action` will be null if you don't have an entry `action` within the form payload.

You can notice that Restlet provides a method `getFirstValue` with a default value parameter:

```
String action = form.getFirstValue("action", "defaultActionValue");
```

This could help you not to have `NullPointerException`.

Otherwise, it seems that you try to implement several actions for a method `POST`. I think that this blog post could give you some additional hints: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/handling-multiple-actions-for-a-post-method/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry